# LINQ Expression Translation Issue: InvalidOperationException with Unmapped Member 'ParkName' in Entity Type 'ParkModel'

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I am encountering an issue while executing a LINQ query in my application, and I'm hoping someone can provide some guidance on how to resolve it. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<ParkModel>()
    .Where(p => p.ParkName != null && p.ParkName.Equals(
        value: __name_0, 
        comparisonType: OrdinalIgnoreCase))' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of member 'ParkName' on entity type 'ParkModel' failed. This commonly occurs when the specified member is unmapped.
Translation of member 'ParkName' on entity type 'ParkModel' failed. This commonly occurs when the specified member is unmapped. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

It seems like the issue is related to the translation of the 'ParkName' member on the 'ParkModel' entity type, and it's indicating that the specified member is unmapped. I have checked my entity model, and 'ParkName' is indeed a valid property.

```cs
 [Key]
        public Guid ParkId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the park name.
        /// </summary>
        public string? ParkName { get; }
```

Here is the relevant portion of my LINQ query:

```cs
public async Task<ResponseStatus<ParkModel>> GetParkByNameAsync(string name)
        {
            var response = await _context.Parks.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ParkName != null && p.ParkName.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            return new ResponseStatus<ParkModel>
            {
                Success = response != null,
                Message = response != null ? "Park retrieved successfully" : "No park found with the given name",
                Data = response
            };
        }
```

I have also reviewed the provided link (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038), but I'm still having trouble figuring out the root cause and how to fix it.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue and found a solution? Any guidance on how to resolve this LINQ translation problem and ensure that the 'ParkName' member is properly mapped would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Skip `comparisonType: OrdinalIgnoreCase`. By default EF Core will translate to `LIKE`.

Comment: The error means that the `.Equals()` method that you are using (with `string` + `StringComparison` parameters) can't be translated to SQL. Even though we write EF Core queries using C# methods, you are only actually allowed to *use* C# methods that EF Core (or an extension library) supports as "can be translated to SQL", which is not the case for this variant. The answer by Steve gives various way to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a database with a case insensitive collation then you can just use `p.ParkName == name`.  If you are using a database with case sensitive collation and want to search case insensitive then I would recommend adjusting the collation for that column to case-insensitive to simplify searching. If you want to force the collation at the query level you can use `EF.Functions.Collate()` to specify a case insensitive collation. Note that this will *not* use existing case sensitive indexes, so if this is a typical search scenario it is advisable to use a collation on the column suitable to the type of searching you expect to do wherever possible.